# How to change -classpath when compiling java

Tags: java, compilation, classpath

This is a really stupid question I know, but I don't really know what I'm doing at the moment.

I downloaded some old source code online, I need to compile it and thankfully the previous developer created a few batch files that will compile all the files. However, I think they are using the wrong JRE because whenever I try to compile I get the error `The system cannot find the path specified`

The command being executed is this:

```
c:\jdk1.3.1_01\bin\javac -classpath c:\jes;c:\jdk1.3.1_01;c:\;c:\jdk1.3.1_01\jre\lib\rt.jar;c:\jdk1.3.1_01\lib\tools.jar    Trait.java
```

So i'm assuming its the -classpath option, but I don't know where my current jdk/jre are. Any suggestions?

Comment: why don't you check all the paths mentioned in the command?

Comment: because they don't exist for me. I can't find any reference to a jdk1.3.1 or any other version at all

Comment: Or at least they aren't in the same place, and I don't know where exactly they would be

Answer (score 0):

if you set java environment variable like this:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\jdk1.5.0_06
PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
CLASSPATH=.;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar
```

you can use command:`java -version` to know the java version.

and user command: `javac Trait.java` to run this code.